# C#, FindControl

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, findcontrol

I'm sorry, but I can't understand why this doesn't work.  After compile, I receive a "Null reference exception".  Please help.

```
public partial class labs_test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            Label Label1 = (Label)Master.FindControl("Label1");
            Label1.Text = "<b>The text you entered was: " + TextBox1.Text + ".</b>";
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label Label1 = (Label)Master.FindControl("Label1");
        Label1.Text = "<b>You chose <u>" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "</u> from the dropdown menu.</b>";
    }
}
```

and UI:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="labs_test" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
Type in text and then click button to display text in a Label that is in the MasterPage.<br />
This is done using FindControl.<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" /><br />
<br />
Choose an item from the below list and it will be displayed in the Label that is
in the MasterPage.<br />
This is done using FindControl.<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>    
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Where do you get the null reference exception?

Comment: Label1.Text = "<b>You chose <u>" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "</u> from the dropdown menu.</b>";

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Courtesy of [Mr. Atwood himself](https://web.archive.org/web/20140218055011/http://www.codinghorror.com:80/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html), here's a recursive version of the method.  I would also recommend testing for null on the control and I included how you can change the code to do that as well.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text != "")
    {
        Label Label1 = FindControlRecursive(Page, "Label1") as Label;
        if(Label1 != null)
            Label1.Text = "<b>The text you entered was: " + TextBox1.Text + ".</b>";
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label Label1 = FindControlRecursive(Page, "Label1") as Label;
    if (Label1 != null)
        Label1.Text = "<b>You chose <u>" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "</u> from the dropdown menu.</b>";
}

private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.ID == id) return root;
    foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
    {
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
        if (t != null) return t;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Good for when FindControl needs to be used, but in this question's example FindControl is overkill.

Answer (score 4):

**When Label1 exists on the master page:**

How about telling the content page where your master page is

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/PublicUI.Master" %>
```

Then making a method in the master like

```
public void SetMessage(string message)
{
    Label1.Text = message;
}
```

And call it in page's code behind.

```
Master.SetMessage("<b>You chose <u>" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "</u> from the dropdown menu.</b>");
```

**When Label1 exists on the content page**

If it is simply on the same page, just call Label1.Text = someString;
or if you for some reason need to use FindControl, change your Master.FindControl to FindControl

Comment: +1, deleted my answer. This is a much easier way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`FindControl` only searches in the immediate children (technically to the next [NamingContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/txxbk90b%28v=vs.100%29)), not the entire control tree. Since `Label1` is not an immediate child of `Master`, `Master.FindControl` won't locate it. Instead, you either need to do `FindControl` on the immediate parent control, or do a recursive control search:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control ctrl, string id)
{
    if(ctrl.ID == id)
    {
        return ctrl;
    }
    foreach (Control child in ctrl.Controls) 
    { 
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(child, id); 
        if (t != null) 
        { 
            return t; 
        } 
    } 
    return null;
}
```

(Note this is convenient as an [extension method](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810125616/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/05/06/asp.net-recursive-findcontrol-amp-extension-methods.aspx)).