# Get dynamically created element by ID in C#

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm dynamically creating some (about 20) textfields for a web form like this :

```
 TextBox propValue = new TextBox();
 propValue.Text = columnValue.ToString();
 propValue.ID = columnName;

 propHolder.Controls.Add(propValue);
```

Then, in another function, I need to get the values from each of them. Is there a way to get the values using the ID's I assigned ?

Comment: I think you are looking for the *FindControl* [method][1]:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457567/c-findcontrol

Comment: @VamsiKrishna , Likely to be ASP.Net web form. Therefore he would need to look into the page lifecycle